# Release "copies" of apps to Google and Apple stores

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Our company provides online datacenter services. For some companies (who pay for it) we offer custom login pages and color schemes with their branding.

For example: www.datacenter.com, www.Customer1.com, www.Customer2.com

Currently I am writing mobile apps for android and iOS to go along with our website.

What I am trying to figure out is if either of these are possible:

1. Release multiple versions of the app (almost entirely the same code) with just a global variable change that would cause different images and schemes to be loaded in.
2. Have the same app published to multiple store listings and when it's downloaded I can somehow tell which listing it came from and load assets accordingly.
3. Something else I haven't thought of yet that is a better option lol.

I know I could load custom assets after the customer has logged in but that wouldn't solve my problem of custom login screens, and I don't want to keep a database of every mobile device using our system mapped to a customer account.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for Android--

Android allows you to use [build flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) to configure the app accordingly, it's mainly used for assets as you mentioned, but can easily be baked into business logic.

I'm not sure if you're inferring a crossplat app build - in which case, the ecosystem is relatively new with [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/) and [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) being your best (albeit very painful) choices.

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin. I'm writing them both natively. Java and Swift 4.

Comment: In which case, Android supports this functionality very well.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can make different build targets that each have their own bundle identifier. You can create different provisioning certificates for the different bundle identifiers and release them as separate apps. Furthermore, you can create compiler flags with the built targets to make sure assets don't go where you don't need them.